# Need to pick individual elements from different lists and store them in a dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

I'm working with Python3.6 (especially Django) and have the following situation to tackle.

I have a dictionary of lists that is being returned to me as the output returned from a previously used function, which is something like this:

```
{'sensor_state_list': ['in_service', 'in_service'],
 'rx_sensor_delta_list': [0, 321144],
 'tx_sensor_delta_list': [0, 321144],
 'discard_sensor_delta_list': [0, 321144],
 'time_list': ['2019-03-08 10:30:11.049860+00:00',
  '2019-03-08 12:47:16.722241+00:00']}
```

As you can see, it contains 5 lists which hold a collection of similar data.

What I intend to do is pick up one instance from each list simultaneously and store them as a set for that particular instance and store that as a dictionary, so I can pass that as my API output and use it for charting.

The output is desire would be something like:

```
{'instance1' : 
              {'sensor_state' : 'in_service', 'rx_sensor_delta': 0, 'tx_sensor_delta': 0, 'discard_sensor_delta': 0, 'time': '2019-03-08 10:30:11.049860+00:00'}, 
 'instance2': 
              {'sensor_state' : 'in_service', 'rx_sensor_delta': 321144, 'tx_sensor_delta': 321144, 'discard_sensor_delta': 123451, 'time': '2019-03-08 12:47:16.722241+00:00'}
```

and so on as the number of instances increase in the source list.

Comment: Do the lists always have same length?

Comment: @Chris: They don't, but I make sure they come to the same length by padding a zero in the first placeholder. Theoretically that should be right because the delta value for the first element and itself should be 0

Comment: Please do not re-add chatty material that has been edited out here, unless you _know_ it is permitted. Technical writing is preferred here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all values are of same length, you can do a dictionary-comprehension:

```
d = {'sensor_state_list': ['in_service', 'in_service'],
     'rx_sensor_delta_list': [0, 321144],
     'tx_sensor_delta_list': [0, 321144],
     'discard_sensor_delta_list': [0, 321144],
     'time_list': ['2019-03-08 10:30:11.049860+00:00',
                   '2019-03-08 12:47:16.722241+00:00']}

c = len(d['sensor_state_list']) 
output = {f'instance{i+1}': {'_'.join(k.rsplit('_', 2)[:-1]): v[i] for k, v in d.items()} for i in range(c)}

# {'instance1': {'sensor_state': 'in_service', 'rx_sensor_delta': 0, 'tx_sensor_delta': 0, 'discard_sensor_delta': 0, 'time': '2019-03-08 10:30:11.049860+00:00'}, 
#  'instance2': {'sensor_state': 'in_service', 'rx_sensor_delta': 321144, 'tx_sensor_delta': 321144, 'discard_sensor_delta': 321144, 'time': '2019-03-08 12:47:16.722241+00:00'}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Austin. This is just what I needed and worked perfectly fine. 

Although just out of curiosity, assuming the lists weren't of the same length, i.e., the delta_lists had a value of (n-1), whereas the sensor_state_list and time_list had a value of (n).
How'd the approach be then?

Comment: @DeathMachine, in that case, what should be the values in `sensor_state_list` and `time_list`? You can pretty much use the same setup. Iterate over the maximum value of list (if lens of lists are 2,3,3,3,2, set `c` as 3) and use `v[i]` if there is `v[i]` else a default value, say 0.

Comment: The values of `sensor_state_list` and `time-list` still would hold values of `in_service` (very rarely "out_of_service") and a valid timestamp respectively.  I will try your suggestion out though and get back to you in case I feel lost again. :D  Thank you